# групировка по нескольким столбцам c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Надо программно сделать аналог метода group by по нескольким полям на язык с #, но проблема в том, что эти поля заранее не определены, и в зависимости от выбора пользователя нужно проводить группировки по выбранным им полям

Скажем есть класс Organization

```cs
public class Organization
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string City { get; set; }
       public DateTime Date { get; set; }
       public string Country { get; set; }
       public string Manager { get; set; }
   }
```

и у пользователя есть выбор по которому с его полей проводить группировки (возможен выбор от 1 до 4 полей)

Comment: `If (...) myCollection = myCollection.GroupBy(x => x.Name); else if (...) myCollection = myCollection.GroupBy(x => x.City); else ...` При этом `myCollection` должна быть типа `IEnumerable<Organization>`

Comment: А если клас Organization идет как одна из таблиц бд, возможно ли както с помощю sql запроса сделать?

Comment: Вы Entity Framework используете или что?

Comment: есть такая возможность